# Нужен скрипт, который восстанавливает базу по шаблону

Tags: php, mysql, sql, скрипт

Добрый день. Есть эталон БД в SQL формате. Возможно ли сделать скрипт, который бы сравнивал структуру БД эталона со структурой БД сайта и при необходимости выдавал отчет о сравнении и генерировал запросы по исправлению?

Желательно скрипт на PHP

Comment: Есть возможность развернуть эталонную базу данных? Чтобы сравнивать не SQL-дамп, а две базы данных?

Comment: да, есть, если это необходимо.

Comment: @ПавелЖуковский Вам для структуры б.д. нужен или для данных. Ответ на вопрос да возможно.

Comment: Мне структуру сверять надо базы.

Answer (score 1):

Я использую связку DbForgeStudio и WinMerge )
В первой создаю скрипт создания структуры, а второй показывает, где изменения.

Comment: Это хорошо, но нужен именно скрипт, который я могу выполнить на сервере.. Желательно PHP или SH

Comment: С sh тогда будет проще, но вот в нем не силен. В win среде для создания структуры использовал: mysqldump --no-data - u USER -pPASSWORD DATABASE > /path/to/file/schema.sql

Comment: И как бы можно выставить запрет на изменение структуры таблицы или бд путем установки правильных привилегий пользователю или скриптам, которые у вас работают с бд. Тогда и сравнение с эталоном не понадобится.

Comment: Вопрос не в том, как изначально запретить, а в том, как это проверить и исправить. Вариант с запретом - не подходит.